# How to convert the NSString time to condition if it's more than 30 minutes

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate

I have an extracted NSString 00:50 which I need to condition if it's more or less than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSString *time = @"00:50";
NSDateFormatter *timeConverter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[timeConverter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSDate *date = [timeConverter dateFromString:time];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
NSInteger hours = [components hour];
NSInteger minutes = [components minute];
NSInteger seconds = [components second];

if (minutes + (hours * 60) > 30) {

    // Do your thing here.
}
```

From there, you can have whatever time or date and extract whatever you need from it, simply add the components you need to the `NSDateComponents` object.

Here's everything you can extract out of an NSDate object:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Nice answer, but i think you have to change @"mm:ss" to @"hh:mm", no?

Comment: Didn't know if it was supposed to be minutes:seconds or hours:minutes.

Comment: Added the hours to the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

If the string has the **fixed format** `HH:MM` then you can just compare strings:

```
NSString *timeStr = ...; // time in HH:MM format
if ([timeStr compare:@"00:30"] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    // less than 30 minutes
} else {
    // 30 minutes or more
}
```

Comment: I think the best answer for such a case)

Answer (score 2):

Here you are

```
NSString *string = @"00:50";
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

int hours = [[components objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
int minutes = [[components objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

if( ((hours * 60) + minutes) > 30) {
     // ...
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this say something like "01:20" is less than 30 minutes?

Comment: Do you need to compare also hours? Edit my answer?

Comment: Yeah I stop and thought about it because the next entry is 1:20 exactly. I'm thinking of multiplying the hours to 60.

Comment: And Martins I think i even better, because in your case it is much more quicker)